# What is the best way to verify email address or phone number during call centre sale?

Tags: email, identity

My company sells products through calls. During the calls a customers PII is collected and used to create the product. This PII includes email. After the product is created, we email the customer a summary of the product and all the details they provided us. However, because the email is not verified, there is the potential risk of the email being incorrect and the customer's product summary (including PII) being sent to the wrong individual, who could use it for nefarious reasons.

How is email verification done when the customer is on the phone for both email or mobile number? In addition, the details provided are used to create the customer's digital identity for them to access our online portal. Again, because the email is not verified, we could be creating a digital identity for the wrong individual (i.e. not the customer but the owner of the incorrect email). What is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Voice calls are subject to error and misunderstanding. You should bring some other means of getting data from user, e.g. web forms or SMS.

Anyways, you better set some arranged response, then send a simple empty verification e-mail to that client expecting that.

For example, you can tell the customer a 2-digit number over the phone which must be written in the  reply to your verification e-mail. You may trust the e-mail as soon as you get reply including that 2-digit number.